# Graph Theory(cut-vertices).

Tags: graph-theory

I have shows that every connected graph has a vertex that is not a cut-vertex.

I consider two cases, if $G$ has a cycle we are done.

If $G$ has not , since $G$ is a connected acyclic graph then $G$ is tree.

and since $G$ must have  leaf. (leaf is not a cut-vertex)

My ideal is correct ?

Comment: Yes, that idea is fine

Comment: Yes, it is correct.